# What is the use of assert.h in cpp?

Tags: c++, c

I had gone through the documents for `cpp`. I came across the header file `assert.h`. I noticed the sample code for the header file.

I have a doubt that this function will only abort the execution of the program without any error response or will it alert with errors for aborting the program.

Does it supports only for the pointer functions?

Comment: Take a look at the Standard [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.2).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it `abort()`s the program if an assertion fails.

Personally I don't use it at all; I program for production environments where it is not suitable to instantly abort the program if there is an error. Instead, I call an error-handling routine (even if that routine just displays the nature of the error and hangs the program, in a completely irrecoverable case).